# Required message is showing on top of page with ui-select2

Tags: html, css, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ui-select

When i am using **required** or **ng-required="true"** with **select** and **ui-select2** element, it works fine.
But the message is showing at top of the page not below the select element.[image]

Here below is my code

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-12  col-xs-12">Status<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                    <select data-placeholder="Pick an Status" ng-model="Status" class="selectUI" ui-select2 ng-required="true">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="1">New</option>
                        <option value="2">Approve</option>
                        <option value="6">Recommandetion Denied</option>
                        <option value="7">Approval Denied</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

How can I solve this and show the message with the select element in my page.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not familiar with ui-select2, but I suspect it hides your `<select>` (and possibly changes the positioning) and replaces it with its own html. View the page source to check.

Comment: I think there will be some css conflict

Comment: yes, i just solved this by overriding the default css behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by overriding the default behavior of ui-select2 with

```
    select2-offscreen,
   .select2-offscreen:focus {
        top: auto !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS code to customize the required message.

```
.selectUI[ng-required] {
    margin-top: 40px !important;
    margin-left: 100px !important;
}
```